# VBA Textbox autocorrect to date format

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I'm new to VBA.
I have a Date textbox for a UserForm in excel. I want to input, for example, 1/25, and when I press Enter, it will automatically change to 1/25/22. The year will automatically correct to the present year (2022 At the moment). It is similar to the date autocorrect when you put a date on an excel cell, but I want it to work on a Userform Textbox.

Lastly, when I put the wrong character, like a single number or letter, it will have a message box to alert me that I need to reinput

Thank you very much!

Comment: Record an Excel Macro setting a cell with 1/25 and formatting it as a Date. Take that logic and put it in the TextBox lost_focus event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ControlSource property to point to an EXCEL cell formatted as date. This cell can be in a hidden worksheet, and it can have a defined name. For example in my case I called cell A1 in Sheet1 as MyDateCell, and set the textbox's ControlSource to =MyDateCell using textbox->right-click-properties. Now the textbox behaves like its corresponding cell.